# My Epic Touch 4G can only boot into Odin mode

Tags: rom-flashing, odin, samsung-galaxy-s-2

Installed ClockworkMod via ROM Manager, selected reboot into recovery via manager and the phone only boots into "Android System Recovery" now. OK button doesn't work to select "reboot now", though long depress does what it should.

I just flashed the EG30 tar file (see comments) successfully, but it booted back into "Android system recovery" again and the ok button will not select on "reboot system now" but long long depress will reboot it... back into recovery though. Any ideas on how I can get the phone to start up properly?

Comment: Flashing stock is the same process as flashing custom via Odin, you just need a stock ROM.

Comment: I can appreciate the duplicate thing, but the questions cited aren't really helpful. I was hoping to find an article that lays it out. Been Googling and not much luck. Was just hoping for an A-Z laying out the files needed, selections to check in Odin, etc. I guess I'll keep searching.

Comment: All you need is the .tar file for the ROM, and the XDA post I link to in my answer to the first dupe has everything you need to do in Odin.  I've also wrote out instructions for Odin myself a few times, e.g. [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9288).

Comment: Oh, my bad. The first one does lay it out, blind... thanks. I just applied the EG30 tar file successfully, but it booted back into "Android system recovery" again and the ok button will not select on "reboot system now" but long long depress will reboot it... back into recovery though. Any ideas? Apologies if I 'm posting this comment to the wrong question. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, that's different now.  I updated the question with that and re-opened.

Comment: I did the battery out and wait thing and took out SD and tried a few more times. Still reboots into recovery. I found a pit file "Epic 4g Touch Pit.pit". Should I try again using selecting that also and re-partitioning?

Comment: Good timing :P yes, though I would try the original ROM I linked below.  Whenever this sort of thing happens with the Vibrant it's recommended to use the original 2.1 ROM, they seem to be more reliable than updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first instinct is to say the partitions are messed up.  I would try using the "shipped ROM" from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Samsung_Epic_4G_Touch/ROMs) and re-partitioning via Odin.  I found the .pit file [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1265023).

Comment: Perfect. Applied "SPH-D710.EG30_CL435734-OneClick.exe" linked to your "shipped ROM" URL and all is well. Was able to apply a Sprint update successfully w/o booting in the stock recovery over and over for the first time too. Thanks!

Comment: @rickwnet That's great, glad it worked out so well.